# Shifting values of a vector in C++

Tags: c++, stdvector

Assuming the following basic vector:

```
 std::vector<int> numbers;
 numbers.push_back(0);
 numbers.push_back(1);
 numbers.push_back(2);
 numbers.push_back(3);
```

What is an efficient way to insert 6 new numbers in between 0 and 1?

Here is my approach right now, but I feel like it's not very efficient:

```
 for (int new_number=0;new_number<6;new_number++) {
     numbers.emplace(numbers.begin()+1+new_number,new_number);
 }
```

The reason I don't like this approach is that **numbers 1-3 have to be moved 6 times**. Is there a way to move these numbers just once instead of doing it 6 times? Then I can use this loop:

```
 for (int new_number=0;new_number<6;new_number++) {
     numbers[new_number+1]=new_number;
 }
```

Here is what I am trying to accomplish:

Vector Before Shifting:

```
0 1 2 3
```

Vector After Shifting:

```
0 X X X X X X 1 2 3
```

Comment: I think we really have to know more about the problem to help, inserting into the middle of a vector is never good, try to avoid it

Comment: @aaronman I need a vector because data must be aligned for an API I am using

Comment: You can use insert-at-end followed by `std::rotate` if you can't insert a contiguous range as in dasblightenlink's answer.

Comment: @KerrekSB: You should make that an answer

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: I like the C++11 three-iterator insertion better :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB: Why is everyone saying that the three iterator insert is C++11? It was there in C++03, probably even in C++98!! That being said, the `std::rotate` solves the problem of not having the sequence to insert as a sequence (pair of iterators), so for some that won't be an alternative. Plus there are too few answers using algorithms :D

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: I'm just parroting. After midnight I don't check what 180k+ people say anymore... (But OK, I'll write an answer!)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is an overload of the [`insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) function that lets you insert `n` identical items:

```
// Add six copies of -1 to the vector starting at position 1
numbers.insert(numbers.begin()+1, 6, -1);
```

You can use another overload that takes three iterators - the iterator where to insert, and a begin/end pair of iterators from where to take the data:

```
// Insert addedNUmbers at position 1
numbers.insert(numbers.begin()+1, addedNUmbers.begin(), addedNUmbers.end());
```

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Oops, thanks for pointing it out! I don't know why I thought it hasn't been added until C++11, even though the link that I posted says "before C++11". Thanks!

Comment: Can you insert a braced list?!

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Hooray. Because in that case, even with disparate sources, I would prefer `insert(v.begin() + 1, { 12, foo(), expensive() })` :-)

Answer (score 3):

If you must insert items one-by-one from disparate sources, so you can't use the range-insertion, one option is to insert everything at the back, and then use [`std::rotate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate):

```
#include <algorithm>

v.reserve(v.size() + 6);

v.push_back(12);
v.push_back(foo());
// ...

std::rotate(v.begin() + 1, v.begin() + 4, v.end());
```

Comment: Can I use `std::move` as well?

Comment: @Grapes: For integers? Why?

Comment: if they are not integers?

Comment: @Grapes: So what's the question? `push_back` takes l- and rvalue references, so you can move in there. My example only uses rvalues, so that's implied....

Comment: Can I `std::move` indexes 1-3, 6 places to the right? Then edit the empty spots?

Comment: @Grapes: There's no such thing as an "empty spot" in a standard C++ container. You would have to construct objects and the overwrite them, paying the price of constructing the unneeded objects. You can use `insert` as in the other answer to insert, say, six zeros, and then overwrite them.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will insert `6` at the beginning of `numbers`:

```
numbers.insert(numbers.begin(), 6);
```

If you want to insert the number 6 after the number one:

```
numbers.insert(find(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), 1), 6);
```

(Obviously, if you don't KNOW for sure that the number is in the list, you may want to check that before you insert!)